# Configure wildcard catch-all email with Postfix

Tags: mysql, email, postfix-mta, catch-all

I have a setup using Postfix with a MySQL database to configure domains, accounts and aliases.

I can set up a catch-all address when using a `@example.com` mail and forward it to `account@example.com`.

Now I want a more advanced catch-all, like `user-%@example.com` to forward all to `alice@example.com` and `prod-%@example.com` forward to `bob@example.com`. `%` should be any alpha-numeric letter combination like `user-1@example.com` or `prod-asdf@example.com`.

Is this possible or do I need to change my setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems feasible enough with slight effort; Postfix supports random user-created aliases via the `recipient_delimiter` configuration directive, so you could set `recipient_delimiter = -` and create `user@example.com` as an alias to `alice@example.com`, and `user-%@example.com` would resolve first via `recipient_delimiter` to `user@example.com`, and from there via the alias map to `alice@example.com`. (If you already have email addresses containing dashes in your domain, you'll need to choose a different delimiter, or those addresses will stop working.)